# Why can't I parse img tags on Facebook app pages with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm building a function to extract image source urls from webpages with Python requests and BeautifulSoup. Most pages work well, but when I tried it on Facebook App pages, BeautifulSoup couldn't find any image elements at all.

When I inspected the HTML my server was getting back, I noticed the Facebook pages are burying the images in commented out sections of the DOM- it's a dynamic HTML generation issue.

My question then, is how best to extract a fully formed img tag string that's in a commented-out part of the HTML but not actually part of the DOM. Is this just a regex job, or can I have BeautifulSoup figure out how to see it?

**Facebook app example:**
http://www.facebook.com/cocacola/app_106795496113635

**Code:**

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

**The HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en" id="facebook" class="no_js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
function envFlush(a){function b(c){for(var d in a)c[d]=a[d];}if(window.requireLazy){requireLazy(['Env'],b);}else{Env=window.Env||{};b(Env);}} envFlush({"user":"0","locale":"en_US","method":"GET","svn_rev":524375,"vip":"69.171.234.48","static_base":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/","www_base":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/","rep_lag":2,"fb_dtsg":"AQAe8p1e","ajaxpipe_token":"AXjpiPEj5XnbBS6r","lhsh":"hAQFiKNUl","tracking_domain":"http:\/\/pixel.facebook.com","retry_ajax_on_network_error":"1","html5_audio":"1","fbid_emoticons":"1"});
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
envFlush({"eagleEyeConfig":{"seed":"2xfQ"}});CavalryLogger=false;window._script_path = "\/profile_page_timeline.php:app_{N}";window._incorporate_fragment = true;
        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/cocacola/app_106795496113635?_fb_noscript=1">
        <meta name="robots" content="noodp, noydir">
        <meta name="description" content=" Facebook is a social utility that connects people with friends and others who work, study and live around them. People use Facebook to keep up with friends, upload an unlimited number of photos, post links and videos, and learn more about the people they meet.">
        <link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href="http://www.facebook.com/cocacola/app_106795496113635">
        <title>
            Coca-Cola - Food/Beverages - Your Stories | Facebook
        </title>
        <meta name="title" content="Coca-Cola - Food/Beverages | Facebook">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/yi/r/q9U99v3_saj.ico">
        <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yU/r/nJkT6_kk3B4.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yB/r/iE5kZURGsmn.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yq/r/-R1g7OGqrFd.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/y5/r/lv-mu7kxrY8.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript">
window.Bootloader && Bootloader.done(["RlYvb"]);
        </script>
        <div id="FB_HiddenContainer" style="position:absolute; top:-10000px; width:0px; height:0px;"></div>
        <div id="pagelet_bluebar" data-referrer="pagelet_bluebar">
            <div id="blueBarHolder" class="loggedOut">
                <div id="blueBar">
                    <div class="loggedout_menubar_container">
                        <div class="clearfix loggedout_menubar">
                            <a class="lfloat" href="/" title="Go to Facebook Home"><i class="fb_logo img sp_6jxgq1 sx_df432d"><u>Facebook logo</u></i></a>
                            <div class="rfloat">
                                <div class="menu_login_container">
                                    <form id="login_form" action="https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1" method="post" onsubmit="return Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)" name="login_form">
                                        <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="post_form_id" value="eeb7846832efec96a2e64cba95741522"><input type="hidden" name="lsd" value="VsBjJ" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="locale" name="locale" value="en_US">
                                        <table cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="html7magic">
                                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="html7magic">
                                                    <label for="pass">Password</label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" class="inputtext" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="1">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="password" class="inputtext" name="pass" id="pass" tabindex="2">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" id="loginbutton" for="uny39o_1"><input value="Log In" tabindex="4" type="submit" id="uny39o_1"></label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="login_form_label_field">
                                                    <div class="uiInputLabel">
                                                        <input id="persist_box" type="checkbox" name="persistent" value="1" tabindex="3" class="uiInputLabelCheckbox"><label for="persist_box">Keep me logged in</label>
                                                    </div><input type="hidden" name="default_persistent" value="0">
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="login_form_label_field">
                                                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/recover.php" rel="nofollow">Forgot your password?</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="next" name="next" value="http://www.facebook.com/cocacola/app_106795496113635"><input type="hidden" name="charset_test" value="€,´,€,´,水,Д,Є"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="lsd" name="lsd" value="VsBjJ"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="timezone" value="" id="uny39o_2"><input type="hidden" name="lgnrnd" value="202334_yY_m"><input type="hidden" id="lgnjs" name="lgnjs" value="n">
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="globalContainer" class="uiContextualLayerParent">
            <div id="content" class="fb_content clearfix">
                <div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/person">
                    <div id="mainContainer">
                        <div id="leftColContainer">
                            <div id="leftCol"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="contentCol" class="clearfix hasRightCol">
                            <div id="rightCol" role="complementary">
                                <div id="rightColContent"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="contentArea" role="main">
                                <div id="pagelet_timeline_main_column" data-referrer="pagelet_timeline_main_column" data-gt="{&quot;profile_owner&quot;:&quot;40796308305&quot;,&quot;ref&quot;:&quot;timeline:app_106795496113635&quot;}"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bottomContent"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="pageFooter" data-referrer="page_footer">
                <div id="contentCurve"></div>
                <div class="clearfix" id="footerContainer">
                    <div class="mrl lfloat" role="contentinfo">
                        <div class="fsm fwn fcg">
                            <span>Facebook © 2012</span> · <a rel="dialog" href="/ajax/intl/language_dialog.php?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcocacola%2Fapp_106795496113635" title="Use Facebook in another language.">English (US)</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navigation fsm fwn fcg" role="navigation">
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/mobile/?ref=pf" title="Check out Facebook Mobile.">Mobile</a> · <a href="http://www.facebook.com/find-friends?ref=pf" title="Find anyone on the web.">Find Friends</a> · <a href="http://www.facebook.com/badges/?ref=pf" title="Embed a Facebook badge on your website.">Badges</a> · <a href="http://www.facebook.com/directory/people/" title="Browse our people directory.">People</a> · <a href="http://www.facebook.com/directory/pages/" title="Browse our pages directory.">Pages</a> · <a href="http://www.facebook.com/facebook" accesskey="8" title="Read our blog, discover the resource center, and find job opportunities.">About</a> · <a href="http://www.facebook.com/campaign/landing.php?placement=pflo&amp;campaign_id=402047449186&amp;extra_1=auto" title="Advertise on Facebook.">Advertising</a> · <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php?ref_type=sitefooter" title="Create a Page">Create a Page</a> · <a href="http://developers.facebook.com/?ref=pf" title="Develop on our platform.">Developers</a> · <a href="http://www.facebook.com/careers/?ref=pf" title="Make your next career move to our awesome company.">Careers</a> · <a href="http://www.facebook.com/privacy/explanation" title="Learn about your privacy and Facebook.">Privacy</a> · <a href="http://www.facebook.com/legal/terms?ref=pf" accesskey="9" title="Review our terms of service.">Terms</a> · <a href="http://www.facebook.com/help/?ref=pf" accesskey="0" title="Visit our Help Center.">Help</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/function si_cj(m){setTimeout(function(){new Image().src="http:\/\/error.facebook.com\/common\/scribe_endpoint.php?c=si_clickjacking&t=6215"+"&m="+m;},5000);}if(top!=self && !false){try{if(parent!=top){throw 1;}var si_cj_d=["apps.facebook.com","\/pages\/","apps.beta.facebook.com"];var href=top.location.href.toLowerCase();for(var i=0;i<si_cj_d.length;i++){if (href.indexOf(si_cj_d[i])>=0){throw 1;}}si_cj("3 ");}catch(e){si_cj("1 \t");window.document.write("\u003Cstyle>body * {display:none !important;}\u003C\/style>\u003Ca href=\"#\" onclick=\"top.location.href=window.location.href\" style=\"display:block !important;padding:10px\">\u003Ci class=\"img sp_46v94c sx_401f21\" style=\"display:block !important\">\u003C\/i>Go to Facebook.com\u003C\/a>");/*ypn0bXTr*/}}/*]]>*/
        </script><script type="text/javascript">
Bootloader.setResourceMap({"VhLvJ":{"type":"css","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yU\/r\/nJkT6_kk3B4.css"},"sbVQp":{"type":"css","permanent":1,"src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yB\/r\/iE5kZURGsmn.css"},"0NL5c":{"type":"css","permanent":1,"src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yq\/r\/-R1g7OGqrFd.css"},"VDymv":{"type":"css","permanent":1,"src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/y6\/r\/mA6ahNFI0KJ.css"}});Bootloader.setResourceMap({"Q6HMA":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/y6\/r\/-B_fBBv_220.js"},"y3kOn":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yz\/r\/WNADMmAL4i0.js"},"cNca2":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yh\/r\/8iHYobZ_uUW.js"},"xbu5O":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yf\/r\/MsjbZFUA3CA.js"},"IdMsN":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yG\/r\/NSXA8EZYqOA.js"},"oW\/FK":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yX\/r\/J7VcVoS5R35.js"},"KuxPB":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yM\/r\/1H5Y5NQHMnu.js"},"rZSx8":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yF\/r\/AMUiJJrPh_6.js"},"H42Jh":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/y3\/r\/ppwOo4BAmlb.js"},"Z5N10":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yq\/r\/LjiCoz6UKXG.js"}}); Bootloader.enableBootload({"ErrorSignal":{"resources":["Q6HMA","cNca2"],"module":true},"Dialog":{"resources":["Q6HMA","sbVQp"],"module":true},"json":{"resources":[],"module":true,"runWhenReady":true},"DOM":{"resources":["Q6HMA"],"module":true},"HTML":{"resources":["Q6HMA"],"module":true},"event-extensions":{"resources":["Q6HMA"],"module":true},"legacy:dialog":{"resources":["Q6HMA","sbVQp"]},"IframeShim":{"resources":["Q6HMA","xbu5O"],"module":true},"legacy:ajaxpipe":{"resources":["Q6HMA"]},"legacy:async":{"resources":["Q6HMA"]},"legacy:PhotoSnowlift":{"resources":["Q6HMA","sbVQp"]},"fb-photos-snowlift-css":{"resources":["sbVQp"]},"Live":{"resources":["Q6HMA","IdMsN","oW\/FK"],"module":true},"PhotoTagApproval":{"resources":["Q6HMA","KuxPB"],"module":true},"PhotoTagger":{"resources":["Q6HMA","sbVQp","KuxPB"],"module":true},"PhotoTags":{"resources":["Q6HMA","KuxPB"],"module":true},"PhotoViewerSubscribe":{"resources":["Q6HMA","rZSx8"],"module":true},"TagTokenizer":{"resources":["Q6HMA","KuxPB"],"module":true},"fb-photos-snowlift-fullscreen-css":{"resources":["VDymv"]},"VideoRotate":{"resources":["Q6HMA","H42Jh"],"module":true},"AsyncResponse":{"resources":["Q6HMA"],"module":true},"PhotoInlineEditor":{"resources":["Q6HMA","Z5N10"],"module":true},"Form":{"resources":["Q6HMA"],"module":true},"DOMScroll":{"resources":["Q6HMA"],"module":true},"legacy:Toggler":{"resources":["Q6HMA","sbVQp"]},"legacy:dom-form":{"resources":["Q6HMA"]},"legacy:Tooltip":{"resources":["Q6HMA","sbVQp"]},"Input":{"resources":["Q6HMA"],"module":true},"dimension-tracking":{"resources":["Q6HMA"]},"detect-broken-proxy-cache":{"resources":["Q6HMA"]},"link-rel-preload":{"resources":["Q6HMA"]}});Arbiter.registerCallback(InitialJSLoader.callback, ["BOOTLOAD\/ROADRUNNER_READY"]);Arbiter.registerCallback(function() {InitialJSLoader.load(["Q6HMA","y3kOn"]);Arbiter.inform("BOOTLOAD\/ROADRUNNER_READY", true, Arbiter.BEHAVIOR_STATE);}, [OnloadEvent.ONLOAD_DOMCONTENT_CALLBACK]);
        </script><script type="text/javascript">
Bootloader.configurePage(["VhLvJ","sbVQp","0NL5c"]); Bootloader.done(["jDr+c"]); JSCC.init(({"j0E2hENIaexzaBuzHe1":function(){return new AsyncLayout();}})); new (require("ServerJS"))().handle({"require":[["WidePageController"],["LoginFormController","init",[],[{"__e":"login_form","root":null},{"__e":"loginbutton","root":null}]],["TinyViewport"]]}); onloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){Arbiter.inform("UserAction\/loadSamplingRates", [{"ns":"timeline","ua_id":"scrubber","rate":100},{"ns":"test","ua_id":"test","rate":1},{"ns":"groups","ua_id":"create_dialog","rate":10}], Arbiter.BEHAVIOR_PERSISTENT)}); onloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){Arbiter.inform("UserAction/enable", ["events"], Arbiter.BEHAVIOR_PERSISTENT);}); onloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){JSCC.get('j0E2hENIaexzaBuzHe1').init("contentArea");}); onloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){window.intl_locale_rewrites = {"meta":{"\/_B\/":"^(.*[.,!?\\s]|)","\/_E\/":"([.,!?\\s].*|)$"},"patterns":{"\/\u0001(.*)('|&#039;)s\u0001(?:'|&#039;)s(.*)\/":"\u0001$1$2s\u0001$3","\/_\u0001([^\u0001]*)\u0001\/e":"mb_strtolower(\"\u0001$1\u0001\")","\/\\^\\x01([^\\x01])(?=[^\\x01]*\\x01)\/e":"mb_strtoupper(\"\u0001$1\")","\/_\u0001([^\u0001]*)\u0001\/":"javascript"}};}); onloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){$("uny39o_2").value = tz_calculate(1331868214)}); onloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){try { $("email").focus(); } catch (_ignore) { }}); onafterloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){Bootloader.loadComponents(["dimension-tracking"], function(){ });}); onafterloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){Bootloader.loadComponents(["detect-broken-proxy-cache"], function(){ detect_broken_proxy_cache("0", "c_user") });}); onafterloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){Bootloader.loadComponents(["link-rel-preload"], function(){ link_rel_preload() });}); 
        </script><script type="text/javascript">
var big_pipe = new BigPipe({"lid":0,"rrEnabled":1,"forceFinish":true,"delay":0,"jsEarlier":0});
        </script><script type="text/javascript">
big_pipe.onPageletArrive({"phase":0,"id":"first_response","is_last":true,"css":["VhLvJ","sbVQp","0NL5c"],"js":["Q6HMA","y3kOn"]});
        </script>
        <p>
            <code class="hidden_elem" id="uny39o_3"><!-- <div id="pagelet_main_column_personal" data-referrer="pagelet_main_column_personal_other"></div> --></code>
        </p><script type="text/javascript">
big_pipe.onPageletArrive({"phase":1,"id":"pagelet_timeline_main_column","resource_map":{"\/zUlm":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yo\/r\/U9HBCtRTNYV.js"}},"js":["Q6HMA","\/zUlm"],"onload":["TimelineController.init(\"40796308305\", \"app_106795496113635\");"],"content":{"pagelet_timeline_main_column":{"container_id":"uny39o_3"}}});
        </script>
        <p>
            <code class="hidden_elem" id="uny39o_7"><!-- <div class="fbTimelineTopSectionBase collapsedHead"><div id="above_header_timeline_placeholder"></div><div class="fbTimelineSection mtm fbTimelineTopSection"><div id="fbProfileCover"><div class="fbTimelineStickyHeader fixed_elem fbTimelineStickyHeaderVisible" id="uny39o_4"><div class="stickyHeaderWrap clearfix"><div class="back"></div><div class="name"><a class="profileThumb" href="http://www.facebook.com/coca-cola"><img class="uiProfilePhoto uiProfilePhotoLarge img" src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/174560_40796308305_2093137831_q.jpg" alt="" /></a><span class="uiButtonGroup fbStickyHeaderBreadcrumb uiButtonGroupOverlay" id="uny39o_5"><span class="firstItem uiButtonGroupItem buttonItem"><a class="nameButton uiButton uiButtonOverlay" role="button" href="http://www.facebook.com/coca-cola"><span class="uiButtonText">Coca-Cola</span></a></span><span class="lastItem uiButtonGroupItem selectorItem"><div class="uiSelector inlineBlock pageMenu uiSelectorNormal uiSelectorDynamicLabel"><div class="wrap"><a class="pageMenuButton uiSelectorButton uiButton uiButtonOverlay" role="button" href="#" aria-haspopup="1" data-label="Your Stories" data-length="30" rel="toggle"><span class="uiButtonText">Your Stories</span></a><div class="uiSelectorMenuWrapper uiToggleFlyout"><div role="menu" class="uiMenu uiSelectorMenu"><ul class="uiMenuInner"><li class="uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption" data-label="Timeline"><a class="itemAnchor itemWithIcon" role="menuitemradio" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" href="http://www.facebook.com/coca-cola"><i class="mrs itemIcon img sp_5y58i6 sx_df81cf"></i><span class="itemLabel fsm">Timeline</span></a></li><li class="uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption" data-label="About"><a class="itemAnchor itemWithIcon" role="menuitemradio" tabindex="-1" aria-checked="false" href="http://www.facebook.com/cocacola/info"><i class="mrs itemIcon img sp_46v94c sx_861aba"></i><span class="itemLabel fsm">About</span></a></li><li class="uiMenuSeparator separator hidden_elem"></li></ul></div></div></div><select><option value="">Your Stories</option><option value="Timeline">Timeline</option><option value="About">About</option></select></div></span><span class="uiButtonGroupItem selectorItem hidden_elem"><div class="uiSelector inlineBlock sectionMenu uiSelectorNormal uiSelectorDynamicLabel"><div class="wrap"><a class="uiSelectorButton uiButton uiButtonOverlay uiButtonNoText" role="button" href="#" aria-haspopup="1" data-length="30" rel="toggle"><span class="uiButtonText"></span></a><div class="uiSelectorMenuWrapper uiToggleFlyout"><div role="menu" class="uiMenu uiSelectorMenu"><ul class="uiMenuInner"><li class="uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption"><a class="itemAnchor" role="menuitemradio" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" href="#" rel="ignore"><span class="itemLabel fsm"><span></span></span></a></li></ul></div></div></div><select><option value=""></option><option value=""></option></select></div></span><span class="uiButtonGroupItem selectorItem hidden_elem"><div class="uiSelector inlineBlock subsectionMenu uiSelectorNormal uiSelectorDynamicLabel"><div class="wrap"><a class="uiSelectorButton uiButton uiButtonOverlay" role="button" href="#" aria-haspopup="1" data-length="30" rel="toggle"><span class="uiButtonText">Highlights</span></a><div class="uiSelectorMenuWrapper uiToggleFlyout"><div role="menu" class="uiMenu uiSelectorMenu"><ul class="uiMenuInner"><li class="uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption highlights checked" data-label="Highlights"><a class="itemAnchor" role="menuitemradio" tabindex="0" aria-checked="true" href="#" rel="ignore"><span class="itemLabel fsm">Highlights</span></a></li><li class="uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption allStories" data-label="All Stories"><a class="itemAnchor" role="menuitemradio" tabindex="-1" aria-checked="false" href="#" rel="ignore"><span class="itemLabel fsm">All Stories</span></a></li><li class="uiMenuSeparator separator hidden_elem"></li></ul></div></div></div><select><option value=""></option><option value="highlights" selected="1">Highlights</option><option value="allStories">All Stories</option></select></div></span></span></div><div class="actions"><span class="uiButtonGroup fbTimelineConnectButtonGroup uiButtonGroupOverlay" id="uny39o_6"><span class="firstItem lastItem uiButtonGroupItem buttonItem"><a class="uiButton uiButtonOverlay uiButtonLarge" role="button" rel="dialog" href="/ajax/signup_dialog.php?page_id=40796308305&amp;next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcoca-cola"><i class="mrs img sp_aoiw5d sx_b3340c"></i><span class="uiButtonText">Like</span></a></span></span></div></div></div></div><div id="pagelet_above_header_timeline" data-referrer="pagelet_above_header_timeline"></div></div></div><div id="timeline_tab_content"><div class="fbTimelineSection mtm pageAppTab"><div id="pagelet_app_106795496113635" data-referrer="pagelet_app_106795496113635"></div></div></div> --></code>
        </p><script type="text/javascript">
big_pipe.onPageletArrive({"phase":1,"id":"pagelet_main_column_personal","display_dependency":["pagelet_timeline_main_column"],"jsmods":{"require":[["Selector"]]},"css":["VhLvJ","sbVQp","noaQ6"],"resource_map":{"noaQ6":{"type":"css","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yZ\/r\/olLHMD8tyzn.css"}},"js":["Q6HMA","\/zUlm"],"onload":["TimelineStickyHeader.init($('uny39o_4'))","TimelineStickyHeaderNav.init($('uny39o_5'), {\"custom_subsection_menu\":true})"],"content":{"pagelet_main_column_personal":{"container_id":"uny39o_7"}}});
        </script>
        <p>
            <code class="hidden_elem" id="uny39o_8"><!-- <div class="timeline"></div> --></code>
        </p><script type="text/javascript">
big_pipe.onPageletArrive({"phase":1,"id":"pagelet_above_header_timeline","display_dependency":["pagelet_main_column_personal"],"is_last":true,"js":["Q6HMA"],"content":{"pagelet_above_header_timeline":{"container_id":"uny39o_8"}}});
        </script>
        <p>
            <code class="hidden_elem" id="uny39o_9"><!-- <div><div id="pagelet_app_runner" data-referrer="pagelet_app_runner"></div></div> --></code>
        </p><script type="text/javascript">
big_pipe.onPageletArrive({"phase":2,"id":"pagelet_app_106795496113635","is_last":true,"has_inline_js":true,"css":["a9lBH"],"bootloadable":{"legacy:dom":{"resources":["Q6HMA"]}},"resource_map":{"a9lBH":{"type":"css","permanent":1,"src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yE\/r\/I3KZ7jvU7mg.css"}},"js":["Q6HMA"],"content":{"pagelet_app_106795496113635":{"container_id":"uny39o_9"}},"tti_phase":2});
        </script>
        <p>
            <code class="hidden_elem" id="uny39o_10"><!-- <iframe name="app_runner_4f62b2364c9a97c52840233" id="app_runner_4f62b2364c9a97c52840233" style="width:810px;height:800px;" frameborder="0" src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4#app_runner_4f62b2364c9a97c52840233"></iframe> --></code>
        </p><script type="text/javascript">
big_pipe.onPageletArrive({"phase":3,"id":"pagelet_app_runner","is_last":true,"is_second_to_last_phase":true,"has_inline_js":true,"css":["sbVQp"],"resource_map":{"4oS\/B":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/y7\/r\/G6XO6uDjJ6r.js"},"OhsqH":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yT\/r\/MIrvOITsbj6.js"}},"js":["Q6HMA","4oS\/B","OhsqH"],"onload":["PlatformAppController.init({\"name\":\"app_runner_4f62b2364c9a97c52840233\",\"config\":[],\"appTabUrl\":\"http:\\\/\\\/assets.facebook.coca-cola.com\\\/contentstore\\\/globaltab\\\/facebook\\\/tabs\\\/attribution\\\/\",\"signedRequest\":\"-fDEufyKDWg38NUBKHDoj0nQHnew1Wh92G75b89OXfg.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTMzMTg2ODIxNCwicGFnZSI6eyJpZCI6IjQwNzk2MzA4MzA1IiwibGlrZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJhZG1pbiI6ZmFsc2V9LCJ1c2VyIjp7ImNvdW50cnkiOiJ1cyIsImxvY2FsZSI6ImVuX1VTIiwiYWdlIjp7Im1pbiI6MCwibWF4IjoxMn19fQ\"})"],"content":{"pagelet_app_runner":{"container_id":"uny39o_10"}}});
        </script><script type="text/javascript">
big_pipe.onPageletArrive({"phase":4,"id":"","is_last":true,"the_end":true,"css":["VhLvJ","sbVQp","0NL5c"],"js":["Q6HMA","y3kOn"]});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is that image tag mangled?

Comment: @Yarin: The first example looks good to me (although the content of the class attribute has a newline in it).

Comment: @Yarin the "html image tax examples" you cite is actually a single `img` tag and is perfectly normal.  The CSS classes simply have a line break in them.  The `img"` on the second line is saying that `img` is a (the final) CSS class for the tag.  Then it continues on with the src and alt attributes.  It's just one tag, and there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks, turns out this is a different problem then what I had originally thought- I've rewritten my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second snippet looks like the final HTML is dynamically generated. To verify, compare what you get via HTTP with what Firebug shows you as the final DOM. You have several options:

1. Reverse-engineer the Javascript code and write Python code to simulate it's behavior
2. Use a real DOM aware browser environment like Selenium or my own library, [dryscrape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape), which uses QtWebkit under the hood and is more lightweight and fast (but only tested on Linux).

Comment: @yarin: You need to post more of the HTML.

Comment: OK, i think i just answered my own question with the HTML - the img tag in question is in some sort of commented out code section. This is some strange dynamic architecture. Would your library be able to parse this?

Comment: @Yarin: it will see the page exactly like a real browser would see it. Nothing more or less.

Comment: That's all I need- Is that because it can run javascript and BS can't?

Comment: @Yarin: Yes, it seems like large parts of the DOM are dynamically generated here.

Comment: @Yarin: Please consider this as an answer if it was helpful (: